# Is there a way to determine a function that could model the transformation of one function to another?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let's say I have a function centered at the origin, say $f(x)= x^2$, at an initial time. After some time has passed, the initial function $f(x)$ has transformed into a different function, say $g(x)=6x^7$. Is it mathematically possible to obtain a third function, say $h(x)$, that models the transition from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$? If so, could this be extended to multivariable functions?

What does this look like generally? What is the method to obtain the function $h(x)$ that models the transition from any $f(x)$ to any $g(x)$ with a time interval between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that allows $f(x)$ to transform into $g(x)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your second function still "centered at the origin?"

Comment: You're looking for $f(x;t)$.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Yes, both functions are centered at the origin.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork From a notation perspective what do you mean by $f(x;t)$? I have never seen that before.

Comment: This means $f$ is a function of $x$ where $t$ is some parameter.  Think of $t$ as choosing which function is in play.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ah okay that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

$$f(x;t) = (5 t + 1) x^{5 t + 2}$$

and try $t=0$ and $t=1$.

Or you could define $h(q)= 6 q^{7/2}$, and then $h(f(x)) = 6 x^7$.

But such approaches are not unique.  There are many functions that will give you the particular functions you state.